# scan directory to find and open the file

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

I want to make a program that lets user enter drive name/folder(`C:\` or `f:\folder\`) and a file name (`test.exe`) then program searches that file in the given drive or folder and opens the file.I managed to do the function that opens the file but cannot figure out how to search the file pass the location of file found to open it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916973/recursive-file-search-using-c-mfc

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Comment: you can go through the following links:
[Recursive file search using C++ MFC?][1]


[How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916973/recursive-file-search-using-c-mfc
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
char com[50]="ls ";
char path[50]="F:\\folder\\";
char file[50]="test.exe";

strcat(com,path);
strcat(com,file);

if (!system(com))  // system returns the return value of the command executed
    cout<<"file not present\n";
else
{
    cout<<"file is present\n";
    strcat(path,file);

    FILE* f = fopen(path,"r");

    //do your file operations here
}
```

Comment: what `ls >` does in the system function?

Comment: Changed the code. It basically writes to file the content of the output. See the [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) command.

Comment: I tried it prints file is present but how do know the path of program to open it.

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie If path and name of the file are stored as strings, concatenate the two and write the system command. Is that what you want?

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie Edited the answer. You got your answer now?

Comment: @RikayanBandopadhyay not tried the code yet but if user only inputs the drive partiton name(containing several folders) and the file name can this program will work then if not what modifications i have to make?

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie You have a better answer now. If you accept the other (better) answer, I can delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use boost::file_system. Here is documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

**EDIT**: after some time, I've got that my ansver were sligtly out of topic. To check if file exists you can use special boost::filesystem function.

```
bool exists(const path& p);
```

**/EDIT**

And directory iterator example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration

It that example used std::copy, but you need filenames. So you can do something like this.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
std::string dirPath = "."; // target directory path
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itt(bfs::path(dirPath)); // iterator for dir entries
for ( ; itt != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); itt++)
{
   const boost::filesystem::path & curP = itt->path();
   if (boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(curP)) // check for not-a-directory-or-something-but-file
   {
      std::string filename = curP.string(); // here it is - filename in a directory
      // do some stuff
   }
}
```

If you are not expirienced with boost - building it can be complicated.
You can obtain prebuilded boost binaries for your compiller and platform at boost.teeks99.com

Also, if you cant use boost for some reason, there is platform specific ways of iterating a directory, but I dont know on which platform you are, so I cant provide you an example.

Comment: possible related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366040/search-files-in-directory-and-subdirectory-using-boost-library-c